# Angular.js app with Salesforce platform

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

I need to create a event app in angular and node.js with login functionality as normal user and salerforce user . How can I create it ? Also I need to manage event on salesforce and update and delete from thre UI .

I want to understand how to create a custom app in angular and how to fetch data from salesforce ? Also how to manage that data on salesforce . I have gone through lot of documents and videos but couldn`t understand how exactly salesforce help me to build my app and can be integrated with it .

Any help appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this Node + Salesforce REST quick start: https://www.jamesward.com/2016/01/13/salesforce-rest-apis-from-zero-to-cloud-to-local-dev-in-minutes

That example doesn't use Angular but you could easily add it in.  Also check out: http://coenraets.org/blog/2015/12/angular2-rest-salesforce/

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help...really a great tutotrial..I also want to ask one thing..I have just created a connected app in salesforce . Do I need to add anything else on salesforce to access account ID or name ?

Comment: Nope, you should only need the Connected App to access Salesforce via the REST APIs.

Comment: Hi ..Thenks for help !! I am not getting from where I am getting the account detail i.e id , name , industry etc ? I cant search these entity on my salesforce account . As I want to fetch the event we create in our salesforce account after login to login.salesforce.com.

Comment: You can explore your data in the Salesforce Workbench: https://workbench.developerforce.com

That will probably help you figure out how to get to your data via the REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide you want to use Angular 2 I have created a boilerplate for getting started. Allows you to develop your application completely locally and deploy to Salesforce only when you want to. https://github.com/iDev0urer/salesforce-angular2-boilerplate